spectrum of weighted sum of projection operators
Let $P_i$ be a collection of projection operators on some Hilbert space $H$, so that $P_iP_j=0$, and so that $\sum_i P_i=Id$, where $Id$ is the identity operator. Assume that there exists a bounded sequence $\lambda_i$ so that the series $T=\sum_i \lambda_i P_i$ defines a bounded operator on $H$. Is it true that the spectrum of $T$ is precisely $\overline{\{\lambda_i:i=1,2,\dots\}}$?
Of course intuitively one would simply like to invert the operator as follows:
For $x=\sum_{i}P_ix$, it would seem that $(T-\lambda)(\sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda}P_ix)=x$. However, because the projections do not have orthogonal ranges, it is not clear if $(\sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda}P_ix)$ is actually in $H$.
Any help would be appreciated!

So you do not require that $P_i$ are selfadjoint.

No, Im assuming they are not. Otherwise their ranges would be orthogonal, and therefore the spectrum would just be $\overline{{\lambda_i:i=1,2,\dots}}$

Do you have any particular example, for instance when $P_i$ are one dimensional, and not orthogonal?

I guess one can construct a stupid example as follows: Take ${e_n}{n \geq 1}$ any orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space $H$, and let ${P_n}{n \geq 3}$ be the orthogonal projection onto the span of $e_n$. Then let $P_1(ae_1+be_2)=(a-b)e_1$, $P_2(ae_1+be_2)=be_1+be_2$. Then $P_1P_2=0$, but they are not orthogonal. Then just set $T=\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n}P_n$.

Of course this example doesn't really capture the "essence" of the question, since only finitely many of the projections are not orthogonal, and I really am interested in the case when "most" of them are not mutually orthogonal.

What follows is a partial answer dealing with the case $\sum|\lambda_n-\lambda_{n-1}|<\infty.$ Then $\lambda_n$ is convergent. Denote $\lambda_0=\lim \lambda_n.$ Then
$$T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_nP_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda_n-\lambda_0)P_n+\lambda_0I$$ Therefore in order to determine the spectrum of $T$ we may restrict to the case $\lambda_n\to 0.$
By the uniform bounded principle the norm of the operators $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nP_k$ are uniformly bounded. Assume a sequence $\mu_n $ satisfies
$$\mu_n\to 0,\quad \sum|\mu_n-\mu_{n-1}|<\infty\quad (*)$$
Then $$\sum_{n=1}^N\mu_nP_n=\sum_{n=1}^N(\mu_n-\mu_{n+1})S_n+ \mu_NS_{N+1} $$
Thus the series
$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu_nP_n$ is norm convergent.
In particular the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu_nP_n$ is norm convergent.
Assume $|\lambda-\lambda_n|\ge \delta$ for all $n$ and some $\delta>0.$ Then $\lambda\neq 0.$
Let $\mu_n=(\lambda-\lambda_n)^{-1}-\lambda^{-1}.$ Then the sequence $\mu_n$ satisfies $(*)$ as
$$ |\mu_n-\mu_{n-1}|={|\lambda_n-\lambda_{n-1}|\over |\lambda -\lambda_{n-1}|\,|\lambda -\lambda_{n-1}|}\le \delta^{-2}|\lambda_n -\lambda_{n-1}|$$
Thus the series $\sum [(\lambda-\lambda_n)^{-1}-\lambda^{-1}]P_n$ is norm convergent. Therefore
the operator $$U_\lambda:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda-\lambda_n)^{-1}P_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty [(\lambda-\lambda_n)^{-1}-\lambda^{-1}]P_n+\lambda^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n\\ =\sum_{n=1}^\infty [(\lambda-\lambda_n)^{-1}-\lambda^{-1}]P_n+\lambda^{-1}I$$ is well defined and the sum representing $U$ is strongly convergent.
As $V_\lambda:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda-\lambda_n)P_n$ is represented by a strongly convergent sum we get
$$U_\lambda V_\lambda=V_\lambda U_\lambda =\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N (\lambda-\lambda_n)^{-1}P_n\sum_{n=1}^N (\lambda-\lambda_n)^{-1}P_n=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^NP_n=I$$
Hence $V_\lambda$ is invertible.
Remark The proof becomes trivial if all $P_n$ are finite dimensional. Then if $\lambda_n\to 0$ and $\sum|\lambda_n-\lambda_{n-1}|<\infty$ the operator $T=\sum \lambda_nP_n$ is compact. Hence its spectrum coincides with the set of its eigenvalues and $0.$ However the only eigenvalues are $\lambda_n.$ Indeed let $x\neq 0$ and $Tx=\mu x.$ There is $n$ such that $P_nx\neq 0.$ Then
$$\mu P_nx=P_nTx= \lambda_nP_nx$$ Hence $\mu=\lambda_n.$

(+1) nice solution!

@Mittens  Oliver, thanks

Thanks a lot for your answer!
